LWC Comboxbox question and data-ids
Wondering if anyone could give me any pointers.
How do you ensure, when you are using a for:each in a template that you are updating the correct comboxbox given you are using the data-id property?
Example
I have two comboboxes. There are multiple records.
box A gets its values from @wire service.
Box B gets it's values from an imperative apex call based on the value of Box A.
Box A --- has some options.
Box B - depending on what is selected in box A it will update Box B.
Box A(1) - same options as Box A
Box B(1) - Depending on what is selected in Box A(1) it will update Box B(1).
The issue I am having is that Box A is also updating Box B(1).
How do I ensure that Box A only updates Box B and Box A(1) only updates Box B(1).
I assume this could be done with the data-id as box A and B have the same data-id value.
Any pointers would be helpful.
Regards,
Vinh
Code.
<template>
<template lwc:if={cartItems}>
                <template for:each={cartItems} for:item="item" for:index="index">
                    <div key={item.Id}>
                       <lightning-card title={item.Name}>
                        <div><lightning-combobox name=Box A" label="BoxA" options={OptionsA} data-id={item.Id} value={item._draftBoxAValue} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-combobox></div>
                        <div><lightning-combobox name="BoxB" label="BoxB" options={OptionsB} data-id={item.Id} value={item._draftBoxBValue} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-combobox></div>
                              </lightning-card>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </template>
            
    //This code gets the values for Box A - all good this is fine.
    @wire(getBoxA,{id:'$value'})
    wiredgetBoxA({data,error})
    {
        if(data)
        {
            this.OptionsA = data.map(record => {
                return{
                    label:record.Name,
                    value:record.Name,
                };
            });
        } else if(error) 
        {
            error = undefined;
        }
    }
    
    I'm guessing there needs to be logic here in the change event.
    handleInputChange(event) 
    {
        const BoxAId = event.target.dataset.id;
        this.BoxAValue = event.target.value;
        //use an imperative method to get values in BoxB
        getBoxB({id: this.BoxAValue})
            .then((result) => {
                this.updateBoxBOptions(BoxAId,result);
            })
            .catch((error)=> {
                console.error('error',error);
            });
    }
    
    
     I think my issue is due to the below logic.
     I'm not sure how to get the data-id of the boxB
    updateBoxBOptions(BoxAId,options)
    {
        console.log('querySelector', this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${cartItemId}"]`));
        OptionsB would be the values in the second drop down.
        this.OptionsB = options.map((record) => {
            return {
            IS there logic I need heren so the values go to the correct BoxB?
            };
        });
    }


It would help a lot if you included a diagram or screenshots

Please add relevant html and javascript to your question. If the update of a field of the first record has an unwanted effect on a field of the second record, this can indeed be prevented by the use of data-id's - although I tend to recommend the use of child components in such cases, depending on the number of fields, required flexibility in adding records etc.

@FelixvanHove Thanks for the reply here is html and JS.

You don't really need to work with data-ids here. You can have a property under the iterating list that keeps options of both the combo boxes.

You can add one more data-* attribute to the combo-boxes that defines if the combo-box is Box A or Box B. You can later use that to query the correct field token.
<div><lightning-combobox name=Box A" label="BoxA" options={OptionsA} data-id={item.Id} data-type="A" value={item._draftBoxAValue} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-combobox></div>
<div><lightning-combobox name="BoxB" label="BoxB" options={OptionsB} data-id={item.Id} data-type="B" value={item._draftBoxBValue} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-combobox></div>

Now when the controlling combobox changes, you know which one to update, should be something like,
handleChange(event){
   const controllingItem = event.target.dataset.id;
   const dependentFieldToken = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${controllingItem}][data-type="B"]`).options = boxBOptions; //the options you get after getBoxB;
}

